# jQuery check if text in list item corresponds to class of a div

Tags: jquery, click, fadeout

I have a dynamically created list of categories as currently follows

```
<ul class="filter_categories">
<li> Cat 1 </li>
<li> Cat 2 </li>
<li> Cat 3 </li>
<li> Cat 4 </li>
</ul>
```

I also have several dynamically created articles in the same page, these have classes that are assigned to them by wordpress, for example, one article may have the class category-cat-1, whilst another may have category-cat-2 and so on. When I click on the List Item with text "Cat 1" I want to fade out the article with class "category-cat-1".

Unfortunately I have no idea how to start this so would appreciate someone to point me in the right direction, then I can refine my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one way you can do it.  Hopefully you can apply this demonstration to your code.

```
$('.filter_categories li').click(function(){
        var liClass = $(this).html().toLowerCase().trim();
        liClass = liClass.replace(' ','-');
        $('.category-'+liClass).fadeOut();
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/trevordowdle/8U3hL/

You can add

`$('.category-'+liClass).stop().fadeToggle();`

If you would rather have `articles` hide/show after each click.

Also if you need to replace more then `1` space with `-`

use `liClass = liClass.replace(/ /g,'-');` instead.

Comment: if you use `fadeToggle`, it should be preceded by `stop` to prevent build-up.

Answer (score 2):

**jquery**

```
$('.filter_categories li').on('click', function() {//on li click
    var ht = $(this).text().trim().toLowerCase().replace(/ /g,'-');//get text/convert to LC/replace
    $('.category-'+ht).stop().fadeToggle();//toggle visibility of related articles
});
```

made a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/filever10/9fDe2/

Comment: this will work only if category have only one space in name. I would reccomend using `.split(' ').join('_')` or `.replace(/ /g,"_")` insted of `.replace(' ','-')`

Comment: this is true. I am just adding it because probably he will have more spaces. it doesn't change the thing that he need to change code and customize it for his own project.

Comment: added regex to fix that.

Answer (score 2):

You started properly with jQuery. 
There's many solutions of this question
I will come with the first one [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/maciekpaprocki/7hydn/7/)

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
jQuery('article').fadeOut('fast');
jQuery('.filter_categories li').click(function(){
    var temp_object = jQuery(this);
    jQuery('article').fadeOut('fast',function(){
        jQuery('article#article-'+temp_object.attr('data-href')).fadeIn('fast');

    })

})
```

});

It should give you some basics of how it's working. You still need to get if() statements so for example if someone will click to fast it will not display two etc.. But it's showing the basics. I would recommend using data-href attribute. In this case it will not fail when you will have some odd names of categories (with "," for example).

I think you thought about fadeIn except of fadeOut but if not just change fadeIn with fadeOut in my sample code

Hope this helps. Feel free to ask in comments I will add more if this is not explaining to much.

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.filter_categories li').each(function(k, v) {
        $(this).click(function() {
            $('.category-cat-' + (k+1)).fadeOut();    
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: this will work only if categories ids are starting with 0 and finishing on the last li so `n-1`.

Answer (score 1):

In jQuery 1.7+, you should use [on](http://api.jquery.com/on/). The below examples binds the event to the `.filter_categories` element, working like a delegate event.

A delegated-events approach attaches an event handler to only one element, the `.filter_categories`, and the event only needs to bubble up one level (from the clicked `li` to `.filter_categories`).

**Method 1**
Assuming there is a sequential naming convention that you can use such as in your question:

```
$(".filter_categories").on("click", "li", function() {
    var articleClass = ".category-cat-" + ($(this).index() + 1);
    $(articleClass).fadeOut();    
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/hadynz/yxjNb/1/

**Method 2**
Assuming that your different article names and corresponing articles will not have any particular pattern, you can use the following:

```
<ul class="filter_categories">
    <li><a href="#" data-article="science">Cat 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" data-article="geography">Cat 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" data-article="math">Cat 3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" data-article="history">Cat 4</a></li>
</ul>

<article class="science">
    Science Article
</article>

...

$(".filter_categories").on("click", "li a", function() {
    $("." + $(this).data('article')).fadeOut();    
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/hadynz/yxjNb/2/

Comment: or they may not always start out with `cat-`

Comment: Trevor - that is possible if he has classes with no common pattern or convention. Anyway - edited my answer to provide a second method that uses data attribute for a bullet proof solution to handle future scenarios for him.

Comment: **method 2** would look for classes like `.science` instead of `.category-science` as described in OP's question

Comment: Yup... it is up to him to update his data attribute to whatever he would like. I purposely used different class names to what he asked for to show that this method will work with any pattern.