# jQuery FadeOut when click on div then fadeIn when click on another div

Tags: jquery, click, fadein, fade

I have several list items that are dynamically created, under these are several articles. When you click on a list item, the corresponding article fades out. This works great, however, what I want is when you click on a different list item, the previous faded out item comes back and the corresponding articles fade out again (essentially I'm creating a results filter)

Here is my jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$('.filter_categories li').click(function(){
    var liClass = $(this).html().toLowerCase().trim();
    liClass = liClass.replace(/ /g,'-');;
    $('.category-'+liClass).stop().fadeToggle();
});
});
```

In the example below, when you click on Cat 1 - the Cat 1 div fades out, however I want it to be that when I click on cat-2, the cat 1 div comes back and cat-2 div fades out.

And a link to JSFiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/Nehe4/2/

Comment: [your problem posted few minutes ago](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20622907/jquery-check-if-text-in-list-item-corresponds-to-class-of-a-div/20623171#20623171). You should just add there. Not saying that my solution works in this way. if you are interested in more advanced filters you can use [link](http://isotope.metafizzy.co/)

Comment: My advice is to use `.stop(true,true)` in this case to avoid bouncing animations and to use `fadeIn` & `fadeOut` instead of `fadeToggle`. Just a good word from a guy who spent some time on debugging ugly behaviors :).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just start the handler by fading in everthing.

```
$("[class*=category]").fadeIn();
```

[(Fiddle)](http://jsfiddle.net/rMx6Q/1/)

Comment: yep that did it, although changed to fadeToggle so it didn't break the toggle later on